# The profile editor WYSIWYG applies markdown but the page requires HTML

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

When editing 'About me' section of the profile page the WYSIWYG controls apply markdown formatting but the data requires HTML formatting.

This is seen in the preview as well as when saved and shown on a profile page.

Current workaround is to manually enter the HTML tags and ignore the helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you used `<p>` tags manually to surround each block in your profile, Markdown does not get rendered inside them. You do have to use HTML there. However, the editor does not and will not ever recognize that you are trying to insert something inside a block of HTML that will not render it.

Your best alternative is to just get rid of the paragraph tags you're using and let the system auto-format the paragraphs for you (just leave a blank line between each paragraph and they'll get formatted the exact same way).

So instead of this:

```
<p>A 17 year veteran of the software development industry, I've worked at large and small consultancies, ISV's and in corporate enterprise IT departments but currently consulting independently.</p>
<p>I'm a Microsoft MVP (in Windows Platform Development) and I run the <a href="http://windowsapps.london/">Windows Apps London</a> User Group.</p>
<p>I'm currently writing <a href="https://www.manning.com/books/intuitive-ux">Intuitive UX: The six dimensions of mobile user experience</a> for Manning.</p>
```

Use this:

```
A 17 year veteran of the software development industry, I've worked at large and small consultancies, ISV's and in corporate enterprise IT departments but currently consulting independently.

I'm a Microsoft MVP (in Windows Platform Development) and I run the [Windows Apps London][1] User Group.

I'm currently writing [Intuitive UX: The six dimensions of mobile user experience][2] for Manning.

  [1]: http://windowsapps.london/
  [2]: https://www.manning.com/books/intuitive-ux
```

And it will work just fine with the Markdown formatting.